# What is Expectation of $-\frac{1}{x}$ where x is i.i.d poisson($\lambda$) distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

poisson($\lambda$) distribution = $\frac {\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$

How can I calculate $E[-\frac{1}{x}]$?

$E[-\frac{1}{x}]$ will be $-\frac{1}{\lambda}$. But I can't derive it.

Comment: Why is iid involved? You have only one random variable $X$ which is $Poi(\lambda)$ and you want to find $E[-\frac 1x]$. First write down what $E[-\frac 1x]$ is by definition of expectation and the Poisson distribution and show it to us.

Comment: Add your attempt please

Comment: oh.. that's right. iid is not involved.
$$E[-\frac{1}{x}]=-\frac{1}{x}P(x\vert\lambda)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{x}\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$
I can't develope more

Comment: There is a positive probability that $x=0$.

Comment: as @paw88789 pointed: the expectation does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The variable $-1/X$ does not have a finite expected value. Note that $X$ could be $0$ with positive probability, whence $1/X$ will be infinite (or undefined, whatever you prefer) with positive probability.

Even if you *could* make sense out of the answer, it would not be $-1/\lambda$. Note that $f(y) = -\frac 1 y$ is a strictly concave function, so by Jensen's inequality we would have $$-\frac 1 {\mathbb E[X]} > \mathbb E \left[- \frac 1 X \right]$$
for any random variable $X$ that can assume multiple values. For your original variable $X$, we have $\mathbb E[X] = \lambda$, rendering it impossible to have $\mathbb E \left[- \frac 1 X \right] = -\frac 1 \lambda$.